# How to code Apostrophe Letter in HTML?

Tags: html, apostrophe

how do you create an apostrophe, but with letters? I'm having trouble on the web finding how to do it with letters instead of quotation, any help here?

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say *with letters*?

Comment: yes, that one is for quotation, but I want to know how to do it with letters, for example, check on google how the logo for "TED x" looks like

Comment: See my updated answer, do you mean the sup html tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would a html entity code solve your problem? You can view them below
http://unicode.e-workers.de/entities.php

For your case `&apos;` for '?

Update: Oh or do you mean the html tag `TED<sup>x</sup>` for sth like
TED<sup>x</sup>

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/sub

Comment: I keep reminding people; http://www.w3fools.com

Comment: is there a way to control the height by any chance?

Comment: Thanks, thought it belonged to w3c, too - interesting text -- No patrick, not as far as I know. You could start playing around with css font sizes or you fake the sup tag with css positioning and pixel values

Comment: Removed the w3schools link, thanks koen